# Removing past location history from Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

I've recently discovered that when I send a message on my phone it will send my location along with it, I have disabled that on my mobile phone, but the previous messages still contain my location (which I didn't turn on in the first place). Is there any way I can remove my location from previous messages on Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to remove past location history. However Facebook has updated its mobile applications such that less accurate location history is shown and it's only shown when you enable it.

See http://newsroom.fb.com/news/2015/06/a-new-way-to-send-a-location-in-messenger/ for more info